Elementor Redirects to 404 Page Not Found on Vehica Theme in WordPress
I am using WordPress with the Vehica Car Dealer theme and Elementor page builder. After importing a demo from the theme, I encounter an issue: whenever I try to edit any page or post with Elementor, I am redirected to a 404 Page Not Found error.
Steps I've Taken So Far:

Updated Permalinks: I have tried resetting the permalinks by going to Settings > Permalinks and clicking "Save Changes."

Checked Plugin Conflicts: I have deactivated all plugins except Elementor to check for conflicts.

Reinstalled Elementor: I have reinstalled the Elementor plugin.

Reviewed .htaccess: I have checked and updated the .htaccess file to ensure it has the correct WordPress rewrite rules.
Question:


What could be causing Elementor to redirect to a 404 page when attempting to edit, and how can I resolve this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
